# show embedded images in google chat in pidgin

Tags: chat, pidgin

I have the enhanced history plugin enabled and my logs are saved as html. When I first opened a conversation in google chat I was able to see embedded images but now the only thing it shows is a link that says "View full image". Is there a setting or plugin that im missing to make it look more like google chat on the web?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Chat plugin has support for inline images out of the box, so you should be seeing them.  Unfortunately, the Conversation Colors plugin (which is normally used to normalise/strip incoming formatting) can swallow inline images.  Turning off that plugin from Tools->Plugins should show the images inline again:

[image: screenshot of Pidgin displaying inline images]